# XML mapping during Documentum to Tridion migration

Tags: xml, mapping, documentum, tridion

Are there tools or utilities for converting Documentum XML files into content in SDL Tridion?

I would prefer a relevant XSL example or an XSLT file for such an XML-XML transformation between the systems.

Comment: As far as I know there's no such tool, but you can relatively easy create one yourself. The Tridion to Documentum connector that is provided only allows usage of artifacts from documentum but not the migration to Tridion.

Comment: After choosing a language and method to modify your xml, consider making another question with your approach and sample code. The xml-to-xml question isn't so much a Tridion issue at that point, but mapping content with one definition to another.

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty simple to create content in Tridion once you understand its object model. If you already know the target schema's details you just have to break it down into

1. Transform XML from Documentum format to Tridion Schema format (this schema is something YOU create in Tridion)
2. Create a program using Tridion Core Service (WCF web service) to create the required components
3. Save them in Tridion

A simple sample can be found here: http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/06/importing-content-into-tridion.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do XML-to-XML conversion via XSL transform or with your preferred DOM-handling API. On the .NET side, consider [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387048.aspx) or alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

There is a new tool available at http://tridionmigration.com for HTML or XML migration into SDL Tridion.

Comment: Relevant answer for this question, though if you'd like to [promote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) your tool, also consider [contacting SO sales](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact).

Comment: Nowhere in that website does it mention the word 'documentum' so how is it relevant?